# encrypt tape files with openssl and tar

Tags: linux, openssl, tar

I am trying to add encryption to my current tape backup scripts by piping the output through openssl, at the moment I have :

`tar -czpvf /dev/nst0 /home /otherdir`

so adding openssl gives this :

`tar czpvf - /home /otherdir | openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -pass file:/my_passwd > /dev/nst0`

which does not give any errors, however the only way I can find on the net to do a decrypt is :

`dd if=/dev/nst0 conv=sync | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pass file:/my_passwd | tar xzpvf -`

this gives the correct file listing but I get :

`bad decrypt
8340:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:461:`

every time.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using different tapes?

Comment: @jftuga I have tried two different tapes so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might have to do with using a block cipher.

I get a similar error when I do:

```
$ tar czpvf - /test/directory |openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -pass pass:password | dd of=/tmp/foo.encrypted.tgz
$ dd if=/tmp/foo.encrypted.tgz conv=sync | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pass pass:password |tar xzpvf -
```

But when I use a streaming cipher like rc4, e.g.:

```
$ tar czpvf - /test/directory |openssl rc4 -e -salt -pass pass:fred | dd of=/tmp/foo.encrypted.tgz
```

I don't get that error.

Comment: Ah, if you're using a block cipher, try the "-nopad" option for openssl.  There must be some sort of junk floating around as an artifact of how the tape stream is being chopped up into plain text blocks.

Comment: Thank you! It was the block cipher that caused it, both of your suggestions, to change to RC4 or add the `-nopad` option worked.  It now decrypts with gzip only complaining about the tar padding [tar and blocking](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/tar/tar_129.html), which is just a gzip tar annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I've seen that kind of error message from OpenSSL is due wrong password. Can you temporarily try if replacing `file:/my_passwd` with `pass:yourpassword` at decrypt line proceeds OK? This, of course, would be a bad permanent solution but try this for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I get the same error message as with the `file:` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pad the input to the block cipher. Try piping your tar to dd with a blocksize of 4k and the conv=sync option. This will pad the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using `mbuffer` to write to the tape as it can handle tape spanning and buffering (reducing shoe shining), and it writes in full blocks to keep the tape drive happy.  See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/854118/64940) for an example script.  `mbuffer` reads from `stdin` so compression and encryption aren't a problem for it, even when spanning across multiple tapes (something `tar` cannot do.)

As to the need to use `dd` with `sync`, this is because of the tape drive's need to write in blocks.  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366217/6662) for a detailed description of why, but the short answer is that again using `mbuffer` to write the data in fixed sized blocks (e.g. 256kB each) solves the issue.